# Default Java exception handling code generated by Eclipse

Tags: java, exception

The default exception handling code generated by Eclipse looks as follows:

```
try {
    methodThrowsACheckedException();
} catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Would it not be better if Eclipse generated the following code instead?

```
try {
    methodThrowsACheckedException();
} catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think so? Why would you want to rethrow a checked exception as a `RuntimeException`?

Comment: I don't think so: turning a checked exception into an unchecked one probably would be cause for some heated discussions! ;)

Comment: Checked vs unchecked arguments aside, I think we can agree that simply printing the stacktrace and moving along is less than ideal.

Answer (score 6):

**You can configure eclipse to do that its your choice**. Check `Code Template-> Catch Block Body` in `Preferences->Java->Code style`

Comment: Both appears same to me generating RuntimeException from Exception class is a code smell. So is just doing printStackTrace.